# Can .emacs read environment variables?

Tags: emacs

I wanted to load some files from a shell environment variable.
Can we check an environment variable in .emacs?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, use the `getenv` function, e.g. `(getenv "my-var")`.

Comment: Or even `M-x getenv RET PATH RET` (it is a command). Likewise, `setenv`.

Comment: How might I pass a default if the variable is not set?

Comment: @daraul `getenv` returns `nil` in that case, so you can use something like `(or (getenv "my-var") "my-default-value")`.